# JQUERY EasyUI - $.messager.alert position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

I am using easyui messager.alert control.

Is there any way to show $.messager.alert on top center of the screen?

```
$.messager.alert({
             title: title,
             msg: message,
             icon: 'info',
             width: 550,

         })
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `style` option on messager.

See here: [Message Box Position](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=Messager&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=#)

## Example

```
$.messager.show({
    title:'My Title',
    msg:'The message content',
    showType:'slide',
    style:{
        right:'',
        top:document.body.scrollTop+document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        bottom:''
    }
});
```

Or in the case of your specific example:

```
$.messager.alert({
     title: title,
     msg: message,
     icon: 'info',
     width: 550,
     style:{
         right:'',
         top:document.body.scrollTop+document.documentElement.scrollTop,
         bottom:''
     }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the message window on the top of screen, please set 'top' property to 0.

```
$.messager.alert({
title: 'Warning',
msg: 'The warning message',
icon: 'info',
top: 0
})
```